# How to debug a page receiving an Ajax POST request?

Tags: ajax, debugging, post

How can I debug a page that receives an Ajax POST request?  For a page receiving a GET request, I would simply manually enter the URL, like:
`http://localhost/.../myAjaxPage.php?paramName1=paramValue1&paramName2=paramValue2`

In this page I would have the `var_dumps` or `echo` needed to make sure everything works as I want it to.

How can I do that with a page receiving a POST request?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `curl` to make POST request from command line.

Chrome developer tools, in the network tab, has "Copy as curl" option when you right-click an XHR request entry. This will give you `curl` command that replicates the request with POST, all headers, cookies, etc.

You could of course also inspect response in the inspector itself. If you can't attach debug information to the response, then you can output it in a custom HTTP header (`<?php header("X-my-debug: $stuff")`, you'll need to add `ob_start()` at beginning of script)

Comment: So my Ajax function is triggered when I click on a button.  Do I need to right-click the button?  I'm unclear on how to "right-click an XHR request entry".

Comment: @JDelage open developer tools (View->Developer->Tools), switch to Network tab, then trigger XHR.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to debug POST responses in your browser, build an HTML form that you can fill and submit manually.  The response will be identical whether you're using AJAX or not.

That being said, your web browser often isn't ideal for debugging server-side code, especially when you need to do more than simple GET requests.  It's often useful to be able to manually set request headers and see the raw response text from your server, and in these cases you're better off using a different tool.  On the Mac, I rather like [CocoaRestClient](https://code.google.com/p/cocoa-rest-client/), but there are many similar programs for other platforms (eg [Wiztools.org's RESTClient](https://code.google.com/p/rest-client/)), as well as command-line utilities like curl.